# Executing prepared SQL in function without loop returning a table

Tags: sql, function, variables, db2, return

I have this source here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SWITCHTEST (CHOICE VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS TABLE ( R_COL1 VARCHAR(1024) ,R_COL2 VARCHAR(1024) )
LANGUAGE SQL
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5);
DECLARE SELECT1 VARCHAR(1024);
DECLARE L_COL1 VARCHAR(1024);
DECLARE L_COL2 VARCHAR(1024);

SET SELECT1 = 'SELECT TEST, DESCR FROM TESTTAB FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY';
SET SELECT2 = 'SELECT DESCR, COLOUR FROM TESTTAB FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY';
IF CHOICE   = 'FIRST' THEN
    PREPARE S1 FROM SELECT1;
ELSEIF CHOICE = 'SECOND' THEN
    PREPARE S1 FROM SELECT2;
ELSE
END IF;

RETURN EXEC(S1);
END@
```

Calling it like

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE (SWITCHTEST('FIRST')) @
```

It should just execute the SQL in the S1 prepared statement and I don't want to use a loop in the function.

I am running DB2 Windows 10.5

Any ideas on how to fix this?

I know that the EXEC(S1) is wrong but I can't find anything on the IBM page that shows how to make this work.

Thank you for your help.

Viking

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? Return a cursor from a proc https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/no/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/t0020511.html

Comment: No I need a function so I can work with the result as a table

Comment: You're looking for what's known as a [table-valued function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/t0053768.html).  It looks like you _might_ be able to do dynamic SQL, but you'd probably be better off if you could just do multiple `RETURN`s.  Also, you need to have a (probably empty?) return for the "default" case.  So, why the dynamic?  Note that you're mostly constrained to declare your **types** ahead of time, so wildly different columns are unlikely to work (except via overriding).

Answer (score 0):

Using intermediate CREATED GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE.

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SWITCHTEST ( R_COL1 VARCHAR(1024) ,R_COL2 VARCHAR(1024)) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS NOT LOGGED@

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SWITCHTEST (CHOICE VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS TABLE (R_COL1 VARCHAR(1024), R_COL2 VARCHAR(1024) )
LANGUAGE SQL
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN ATOMIC

DELETE FROM SWITCHTEST;
IF CHOICE='FIRST' THEN 
  INSERT INTO SWITCHTEST SELECT TEST, DESCR FROM TESTTAB FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
ELSEIF CHOICE='SECOND' THEN
  INSERT INTO SWITCHTEST SELECT DESCR, COLOUR FROM TESTTAB FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
END IF;
RETURN SELECT R_COL1, R_COL2 FROM SWITCHTEST;
END@
```

Comment: As you can see above in my source I need the sql statements in a variable that I then execute.

Comment: No way to do it then. Only static statements.

Comment: OK Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it fits your needs, but you can use a case expression to choose columns for the result table. I don't think fetch first is supported in functions, but you can add that in the call:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SWITCHTEST (CHOICE VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS TABLE ( R_COL1 VARCHAR(1024) ,R_COL2 VARCHAR(1024) )
LANGUAGE SQL
READS SQL DATA
    RETURN
        SELECT CASE CHOICE WHEN 'FIRST' THEN TEST ELSE DESCR END
             , CASE CHOICE WHEN 'FIRST' THEN DESCR ELSE COLOUR END
        FROM TESTTAB ;

SELECT * FROM TABLE (SWITCHTEST('FIRST')) 
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```